# Restkit/Core Data relationship mappings, entity to same type of entity (parent/child)

Tags: ios, rest, core-data, restkit

I am following the [Alexander Edge tutorial](http://www.alexedge.co.uk/blog/2013/03/08/introduction-restkit-0-20/) on RestKit 0.2.0 but I am confused about how to apply it to my needs. Specifically, I am consuming a web service that returns objects in the following structure:

```
{
    "ObjectIdMember": 200,
    "ObjectNameMember": "Baseball Bat",
    "SubObjectIdMember": 4124
},
{
    "ObjectIdMember": 200,
    "ObjectNameMember": "Baseball Glove",
    "SubObjectIdMember": 4555
},
```

The idea is that an `Object` entity can have many sub-objects. Roughly speaking, the purpose of getting the `Object` is to use the `DisplayName` to populate section headers in a table view, and group sub-objects in sections by object.

How do I capture this sort of relationship (or define it) using RestKit + Core Data? The tutorial only suggests what you might do if there is a subobject defined in the response, but this is a different situation.

I know that I could just decorate and use a subclass of `Object` with a `-(NSArray *)getSubObjects`, but Core Data would not be aware of what I was doing in the sense that this would not be using any relationships.

Comment: Can you just map the objects as individual items then fetch from the store with predicates to get only the appropriate members and sub objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is [RKConnectionDescription](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKConnectionDescription.html), which can establish a relationship in Core Data using foreign keys.

The example in the docs gives the following json:

```
{ "project": 
    { "id": 12345, 
      "name": "My Project",
      "userID": 1
    }
}
```

with the following mapping configuration:

```
NSEntityDescription *projectEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSRelationshipDescription *userRelationship = [projectEntity relationshipsByName][@"user"];
RKConnectionDescription *connection = [[RKConnectionDescription alloc] initWithRelationship:userRelationship attributes:@{ @"userID": @"userID" }];
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I was looking for. I think I need to read up more on Core Data to really appreciate what it's doing.